# How to compute the value of specific numbers from a txt file in Python?

Tags: python

I am wondering how I can output the "total value" of my inventory, and have only been able to successfully extract the numbers I want from the txt file using this code:

```
            def value():
                stock_value = open("stock.txt")
                for line in stock_value.readlines():
                    N = re.compile(r'(\d+)|-Side')
                    n = N.findall(line)
                    print(n)
```

For the input file, the first number of each line is the "price", and the second number is "quantity". I wish to multiply the price by quantity of each line, and then sum the total up and output into a total value. How can I do this?

My input file is:

```
Lion, 10, 2, Cat
Persian, 19, 4, Cat
```

I am trying to get my output to look something like this:

```
Total value:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just multiply and sum it and return the value.

```
def value():
    stock_value = open("stock.txt")
    result = 0    # init sum as 0
    for line in stock_value.readlines():
        N = re.compile(r'(\d+)|-Side')
        n = N.findall(line)
        result += float(n[0]) * float(n[1])  # multiply two values and add to result

    return result
```